# Check from token reset password Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Please look below to the picture and the code:

[image]

```
  const { push, query } = useRouter();
  const [Datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const token = query.token;
  //
  axios
    .get(variables.API_URL + `Auth/reset-password/${token}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      setDatas(response.data);
      console.log(Datas);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  //
  console.log("Data:", Datas);
```

When the page is load I do not understand why the token on first request undefined.

the value not undefined

Answer (score 0):

when page is load that time router is undefined
so you have to wrap your api call in useEffect and give router.query as dependency
and in useEffect use if condition
your code look like

```html
useEffect(() => {
   if(router?.query){
  axios
    .get(variables.API_URL + `Auth/reset-password/${token}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      setDatas(response.data);
      console.log(Datas);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  //
  console.log("Data:", Datas);
}
},[router.query])
```

and if you have fix that every time token will come with query than you add router.query.token as dependency and in if condition also replace with router.query.token